# Two first columns of text file as a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, split

I would like to define a dictionary using the 2 first columns of a text file (with a tab delimiter).

Using the following code, I create a dictionary "dict" in which the keys are the rows in the first column and the values are the rows in the second and third columns:

```
mydict = {}
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    mydict = dict(x.split(" ", 1) for x in f)
```

However, I would like to discard the third column and use the first column as a key and the second as a value in the dictionary "dict". I tried this code but it does not work for me:

```
mydict = {}
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    mydict = dict(x.split(" ", 2)[0:1] for x in f)
```

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Comment: You can't call your dictionary `dict` and still use `dict()`, you are shadowing the built-in type.

Comment: Your slice only selects **one** of the split results. If you want the first two elements, use `[0:2]` or `[:2]` (equivalent).

Comment: Side note: I'd use the CSV module for this: `reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')`, then `result = dict(row[:2] for row in reader)` or, with an additional `from operator import itemgetter`, use `result = dict(map(itemgetter(0, 1), reader))`.